# why Interface Builder can`t recognize my new table view controller

Tags: ios

I add a table view controller in my storyboard and add a table view controller class in my project, but when I custom the class the Interface Builder can`t recognize my view controller class. I use Xcode 6.1.1 and swift.

I select the table view controller and type "ChecklistViewController" into "Custom class" manually, but when running it, I got a message say "Unknown class ChecklistViewController in Interface Builder file."

This is my tale view controller class:

```
import UIKit

class ChecklistViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChecklistItem") as UITableViewCell
    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: Add one more delegate method in this controller `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` and then try again.

Comment: Not work. I forget to say that I have added the two method.

Comment: Make sure that you select the tableview controller in storyboard not the tableview.Or you just copy the class name "ChecklistViewController"in to "Custom class",then run it to check if it works

Comment: Not work, I select the table view controller and type "ChecklistViewController" into "Custom class" manually, but when running it, I got a message say "Unknown class ChecklistViewController in Interface Builder file."